# Different form actions depending on button

Tags: forms, menu, onclick

I have a scroll menu and three different buttons on the page.  If one button is clicked, then the form launches a file passing the value selected from the menu.  If the 2nd button, and so on for the 3rd, to launch a 2nd or 3rd page.  I've tried several theories with Java and have come up empty.